# Reference to a pointer error. No instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

The error is: No instance of overloaded function "BSTree::Retrieve" matches argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match).

argument types are: (`int`, `Account*`, `BSTree::Node*const`)

object type is: `const BSTree`

It's saying the argument type is `Account *` but I have it as `Account *&acct`.

First parameter is object to retrieve. Second holds pointer to found object.

Here's the code:

```
bool BSTree::Retrieve(int ID, Account *&acct, Node *leaf)
{
    if(leaf != NULL)
    {
        if(ID == leaf->pAcct->getID())
        {
            acct = leaf->pAcct;
            return true;
        }
        if(ID < leaf->pAcct->getID())
        {
            return Retrieve(ID, acct, leaf->left);
        }
        else
        {
            return Retrieve(ID, acct, leaf->right);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        acct = NULL;
        return false;
    }
}

bool BSTree::Retrieve(int ID, Account *&acct) const
{
    return Retrieve(ID, acct, root);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing references to pointers in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling a non-const method (which can modify the object) from a const method (which is not allowed to do so). It will be an error.
2. Are you sure you want `Account *&` ? From your code, if you want to retrieve a node by it's ID from the BSTree, you will need a `Account*`.

For point 1 [see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40accf6076314f0d) here.

```
a.g(); // invokes an error because g() (which is const) calls f() which is non-const.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Account *&acct` is a pointer to a reference.
That means that `acct` will act as a reference to a *pointer* given as argument. What your function expects as argument is passing an actual pointer and not an existing reference.

You can try this:

```
bool BSTree::Retrieve(int ID, Account *&acct) const
{
    Account* acctPtr = acct;
    return Retrieve(ID, acctPtr, root);
}
```

You can look at a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c).

Apart from that, you are trying to invoke a *non-const* method from a *const* one. You could use `const_cast` in order to fix this but it is **NOT** recommended as it is dangerous and you should search for better alternatives (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047161/call-a-non-const-member-function-from-a-const-member-function) for more).