# calling non const function from const function

Tags: c++, linked-list, constants

I am trying to write a print function which prints in reverse order elements of linked list. It works only when I declare the function non-const with const it does not work and throw below error.

```
cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const slist<int>' to 'slist<int> &'
```

I saw few SO post with regard to it like below 
[Call a non-const member function from a const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047161/call-a-non-const-member-function-from-a-const-member-function) 
and the associated post with that link but I am unable to understand it. If someone can help me understand it

My code : 
Gives error : `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const slist<int>' to 'slist<int> &'`

```
void slist<T>::print_with_recursion() const
{
    node<T>* head = _first;
    print_reverse(head);

}

void slist<T>::print_reverse(node<T>* head)
{
    if (head) 
    {
        print_reverse(head->_next);
        cout << head->_data << endl;
    }
}
```

if I remove const I dont get any error. Also if there is better way to implement printing linked list in reverse order give function definition print_with_recursion() const please do suggest.

Comment: You can't call a non-const (`print_reverse`) member function from a const member function.

Comment: Is it any reason why the `print_reverse` is non-const?

Comment: Thank u - however the problem statement which has been given is to implement print function for given definition print_with_recursion() const, what would be best way to achieve it in that case ? I just got it working as a workaround

Comment: *"but I am unable to understand it"* - That's about as helpful as "it doesn't work". **What exactly** do you not understand?

Comment: @NO_NAME: I think I got it - if I declare print_reverse as const it works fine and the point as well const function can have only const function inside it .. thanks :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl - What I did not understand clearly before the post was we should call const function only inside defined const function. Now you can say why I didnt get it at first go by reading post - I am clueless too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is const but calling a non-const member function (`print_reverse`) which is not allowed.

There's no reason why any of this shouldn't be fully const as you don't need to change any of the data of the object. Try instead:

```
void slist<T>::print_with_recursion() const
{
    const node<T>* head = _first;
    print_reverse(head);
}

void slist<T>::print_reverse(const node<T>* head) const
{
    if (head) 
    {
        print_reverse(head->_next);
        cout << head->_data << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for quick reply - I understand it now, not sure why I was missing the simple point

Answer (score 2):

> if I remove const I dont get any error

That is the best solution. You should make it a habit of making any function that does not need to change its state a `const` member function.

Coming to your particular problem, you can make `print_reverse` a non-member function

```
template <typename T>
void print_reverse(node<T>* head)
{
    if (head) 
    {
        print_reverse(head->_next);
        cout << head->_data << endl;
    }
}
```

Then, there is no need to worry about `const`-ness of the function.

I would suggest the additional change of making the `std::ostream` an argument to the function.

```
template <typename T>
void print_reverse(node<T>* head,
                   std::ostream& out)
{
    if (head) 
    {
        print_reverse(head->_next, out);
        out << head->_data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u - however the problem statement which has been given is to implement print function for given definition print_with_recursion() const, what would be best way to achieve it in that case ?

Comment: @thedreamer, I would make `print_reverse`  non-member function, then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that class member functions have a hidden parameter of that class type.  So

```
void slist<T>::print_with_recursion() const
```

is actually

```
void slist<T>::print_with_recursion(const slist<T> *) const
```

and

```
void slist<T>::print_reverse(node<T>* head)
```

is

```
void slist<T>::print_reverse(slist<T> *, node<T>* head)
```

So when you are in `print_with_recursion()` the this pointer is a `const slist<T> *` and when you call `print_reverse()` you try to pass that `const` pointer to a function expecting a non `const` pointer.

You can fix this by making `print_reverse()` `const` as then it will take a `const slist<T> *` instead of a `slist<T> *`.  It is also a good idea to mark functions that will not change the state of the object as `const`.