# trouble creating a custom sort in C++ for a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to create a custom sort for a vector of class pointers by using a sort predicate:

```
struct sort_by_airtime                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                 
    inline bool operator() (const Network *n1, const Network *n2)                                                 
    {                                                                                                             
      return (n1->airtime() < n2->airtime());                                                                     
    }                                                                                                             
};
```

For each network, we sort by a float returned by airtime().

Now, I try to use this as follows:

```
std::vector<Network *> Simulator::sort_networks(std::vector<Network *> netlist, bool sort_airtime) {

  std::vector<Network *> new_netlist = netlist;

  if(sort_airtime) {
    sort(new_netlist.begin(), new_netlist.end(), sort_by_airtime());
  }

}
```

However, I get a lot of errors like this:

```
In file included from Simulator.cpp:7:
Simulator.h: In member function ‘bool Simulator::sort_by_airtime::operator()(const Network*, const Network*)’:
Simulator.h:48: error: passing ‘const Network’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘virtual float Network::airtime()’ discards qualifiers
Simulator.h:48: error: passing ‘const Network’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘virtual float Network::airtime()’ discards qualifiers
```

Am I not specifying the argument passed to the predicate properly?  airtime() is implemented by classes that inherit the Network class.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly say 'inline' when you define a function inside a class (or struct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your member function should be declared as `const` member function as:

```
virtual float Network::airtime() const 
                                 ^^^^^ //this makes the function const
```

because the pointers which you're using in `operator()` are pointing to `const` objects of type `Network`.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is warning you that `Network::airtime()` is ignoring the `const` qualifiers on `n1` and `n2`.

The solution would be to create a "`const`-correct" version of `Network::airtime()` (assuming it actually doesn't modify anything).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856839/312566) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

`Network::airtime()` is not `const`, and so can't be called via the `const Network*` you have in `sort_by_airtime`.

If possible, the best solution is to make `airtime()` const; otherwise change the `sort_by_airtime` arguments to `Network*`.