# c++ function code generalization using template

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, metaprogramming, containers

I am writing a stl-like container class which has the following functions:

```
    Iterator begin(){
        return Iterator(data_.begin(), 1);
    }

    ConstIterator begin() const{
        return ConstIterator(data_.begin(), 1);
    }
```

I think I could make one function to replace both:

```
    template <typename itr0, typename itr1>
    itr0 begin(){
        return itr1(data_.begin(), 1);
    }
```

and when I call the following, the code is generated in compile time:

```
    Iterator it = foo.begin<Iterator, Iterator>();
    ConstIterator it = foo.begin<ConstIterator const?, ConstIterator>();
```

My first question is, what typename is actually `ConstIterator begin() const`?

Secondly, is there a way to make it so that this metaprogramming is transparent from outside of the class? i.e. I could still use the following code to call begin() as if it was written in a standard way?

```
    C foo;
    const C foo2;
    Iterator it = foo.begin();
    ConstIterator it = foo2.begin();
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 template parameters on your begin method?

Comment: @fontanini hmm because I am not sure what typename ConstIterator begin() const has, so whether itr0 and itr1 are the same for the const case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to define the two methods separately since, as you've noted, their signature differs by the `const` modifier.  There's no template wizardry available that can overcome that (at least none that I'm aware of).

You can however use a number of different techniques to combine their implementations into a single method.  Here's one such option that avoids the need for any `const_cast`'ing:

```
struct Container
{
    template< typename I, typename C >
    friend I begin_impl( C & c ){
      return I( c.data_.begin(), 1 );
    }

    Iterator begin(){
        return begin_impl< Iterator >( *this ); // *this is "Container"
    }

    ConstIterator begin() const{
        return begin_impl< ConstIterator >( *this ); // *this is "Container const"
    }
};
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters) for more options.

Comment: `typename C` looks strange to me, why not just use `Container`?

Comment: @user2k5 Sorry, I could have made that more clear.  When called from `begin()`, `C` will be `Container`.  But when called from `begin() const`, `C` will be `Container const`.

Comment: @AndrewDurward thanks for the answer. This is one of the moment if there exists a solution, it's easy to find it. But if there exists none, I need to find people confirming it :)

Comment: @Andrew Nice use of template in this case and good explanation. And you don't really need to say sorry... :)

Comment: @AndrewDurward I am a little bit failing with my c++ skills... If I put your code directly into my project, begin_impl cannot be seen from the latter 2 functions... error is "undeclared begin_impl"

Comment: @YCHAI Strange, it works both on [ideone](http://ideone.com/T3SAo) (which uses gcc 4.3.4) as well as MSVC2008.

Comment: @AndrewDurward well, my Container is a class instead of a struct, maybe that's the difference? And I don't want to move begin_impl to the outside of the function, also the compiler prevents me to declare it as static...

Comment: @YCHAI My only suggestion is to start a new question with a complete description of the problem.