# const overloading without having to write function twice

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant solution to duplicate, const and non-const, getters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters)

Say I have a c++ class with a memberfunction which is overloaded for const, like this:

```
        Type*  DoSomething();
const   Type*  DoSomething() const;
```

If this is a larger, more complex member, how does one prevent having to write the same code twice ? Can't call any non-const functions from the const one. And calling the const version from the non-const one results in a const pointer wich has to be cast to non-const (wich smells a bit imo).

Comment: The cast is the way Scott Meyers suggests in Effective C++ as do various dupes of this question on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delegate to a template static member function, as in:

```
class Widget
{
    Type member;

    template<typename Result, typename T>
    static Result DoSomethingImpl(T This)
    {
        // all the complexity sits here, calculating offsets into an array, etc
        return &This->member;
    }

public:
            Type*  DoSomething() { return DoSomethingImpl<Type*>(this); }
    const   Type*  DoSomething() const { return DoSomethingImpl<const Type*>(this); }
};
```

In C++11, you can even get rid of the non-inferred template argument, with:

```
static auto DoSomethingImpl(T This) -> decltype(This->member)
```

Comment: Interesting twist. I have not see the template(ing) of the private method before.

Comment: Looks like Steve Jessop mostly described this in his answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/858893/103167), although I think a private static member function is cleaner.

Comment: @Ben i don't see the point of using a static member function. why not we use a const private member function?

Comment: @ggg: I think you failed to understand the original question.  What is the type of `member` inside a const member function?

Comment: @BenVoigt you can make it mutable

Comment: @ggg: But the member isn't supposed to be changed from `const` member functions.  `mutable` isn't appropriate here, it's just a hack, and this answer avoids the problem cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

You did it once, and to do it second time with a const attribute on the class, you can use `const_cast`:

```
class Foo
{
          Type*  DoSomething()
  {
    // Lots of stuff
  }
  const   Type*  DoSomething() const
  {
    return const_cast<Foo*>(this)->DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution was described in the question (with the quite correct note that `const_cast` smells)

Comment: ... and the smell was shaped up

Answer (score 1):

Use the [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern to extract the common code from them. Eg.

```
inline const T* prev(size_t i) const
{
    return &FBuffer[ AdjustIndex(i) ];
}

inline T* prev(size_t i)
{
    return &FBuffer[ AdjustIndex(i) ];
}

inline size_t AdjustIndex( size_t i ) const
{
    return Math::ModInt( static_cast<int>( FHead ) - 1 - i, static_cast<int>( FBuffer.size() ) );
}
```

This technique can be applied in many cases (but not all of them, i.e. if the behavior differs significantly).