# Compiler warning on "Effective C++"s method to avoid duplication in const and non-const member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, constants, overloading

**This question has been updated. Please review the code.**

The following code was compiled with VC++ Nov 2012 CTP. Scott Meyers' book "**Effective C++**" recommend that we should use the method of  to avoid duplication in const and non-const member functions. However, the following code cause a warning (level 1). Because WDK build tool treats warnings as errors, so the following code cannot be compiled successfully.

Is there other better method?

```
struct A
{
    int n;

    A(int n)
        : n(n)
    {}

    int Get() const
    {
        return n;
    }

    int Get()
    {
        return static_cast<const decltype(*this)&>(*this).Get();
    }
};

int main()
{
    const A a(8);

    //
    // warning C4717: 'A::Get' : recursive on all control paths,
    // function will cause runtime stack overflow
    //
    a.Get(); 
}
```

Comment: Not sure it is related in any way to the warning, but conceptually your `const` version should be `const int& Get() const`, i.e. returning reference to const.

Comment: In this particular case, the "duplication" would be `return n;`. How is this an improvement on that? We see that introducing extra code might sometimes also cause extra errors...

Comment: This is a bad example because you actually don't need the non-const Get here. Apart from that, decltype does not behave like you expected. You're not really adding a const this way, so you have an endlessly recursive call. `decltype(*this)` yields A& in your case and since references are not objects adding const will be ignored.

Comment: @xmllmx - I don't think Scott Meyers actually recommends avoiding duplication *at any cost*, he is just offering an alternative for some cases. If avoiding repetition is the goal, and not the means, you can just use `return n + 0;` and `return n - 0;` to make the code different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've transposed the bodies of the two `Get` methods, so the compiler is correct; the const `Get` method is calling itself.  Aren't you glad now that your build tool treats warnings as errors? :)

Swap them round:

```
int& Get()
{
    return const_cast<int&>(static_cast<const A&>(*this).Get());
}

const int& Get() const
{
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thus the compiler warning is valid.

Answer (score 4):

I believed you got it reverse. This is the non-const version which casts away constness on the const version.

See: [Elegant solution to duplicate, const and non-const, getters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the updated question.
(You should have made this a new question)

In `static_cast<const decltype(*this)&>(*this)`, `*this` is an lvalue of type `A`, so the type denoted by `decltype(*this)` is `A&` (see 7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]/4).

As a result your non-const `Get()` function is equivalent to:

```
int Get()
{
    typedef A & Aref;
    // IMHO a const_cast would be the better choice here
    return static_cast<const Aref&>(*this).Get();
}
```

*cv-qualifiers* on a reference type are ignored. With reference-collapsing, your cast is ultimately equvalent to `static_cast<A&>(*this)`, so you don't add the const you need.

So using `decl_type`does not work here. If you very badly want to use it, you'd need:

```
int Get()
{
    // Made my suggested change of cast here
    return const_cast<const std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type&>(*this).Get();
}
```

Comment: Yes. I did. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133644/why-does-decltypethis-not-return-the-correct-type