# Why does decltype(*this) not return the correct type?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, overloading, decltype

The following code was compiled with VC++ Nov 2012 CTP. But the compiler gave a warning.

I just wonder whether this is a bug of VC++ Nov 2012 CTP.

```
struct A
{
    int n;

    A(int n)
        : n(n)
    {}

    int Get() const
    {
        return n;
    }

    int Get()
    {
        //
        // If using "static_cast<const A&>(*this).Get();" instead, then OK.
        //
        return static_cast<const decltype(*this)&>(*this).Get(); // Warning!
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(8);

    //
    // warning C4717: 'A::Get' : recursive on all control paths,
    // function will cause runtime stack overflow
    //
    a.Get(); 
}
```

Comment: Unless you really do more than just return a value in the constant `Get`, you could just do the same in the non-constant `Get` function. I actually don't see a reason for the non-const `Get`.

Comment: The example code is just for proof of concept. The real function of Get() is pointless here.

Comment: Isn't `a` const already? Why would it even warn about the non-const `Get` function?

Comment: @Shahbaz, that's my fault, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`decltype` applied to an expression that's not an id-expression gives you a reference, so `decltype(*this)` is already `A&`, and you can't make that `const` again. If you really wanted to use `decltype`, you could do something like this:

```
static_cast<std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type const &>(*this)
```

Or even this:

```
static_cast<std::add_lvalue_reference<
                 std::add_const<
                      std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type
                 >::type
            >::type
>(*this)
```

Of course it's much simpler to just say `static_cast<A const &>(*this)`.

Comment: So, in conclusion, the warning is valid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm surprised it's not actually an *error*.

Comment: I'm not surprised really. `int foo() { return foo(); } int main() { foo(); }` doesn't error, either, (or does it?!) even though it's an equivalent program.

Comment: Interestingly clang (at least on my Apple) throw no warnings (but does recurse into never-never-land.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I misread this answer. I deleted the previous comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That is good point. Actually the MSVC++ is giving warning because of superficial reason, not the *actual* reason.