# Is it bad to use const_cast to factor out getters?

Tags: c++

Is there anything wrong with using `const_cast` in situations like this?

```
class List
{
public:
    const List * head () const
    {
        // seek to the head of the list
    }

    List * head ()
    {
        return const_cast <List *> (((const List *)this) -> head ());
    }
};
```

It seems clear to me that, assuming there are no strange tricks in the const version of the function, it should always be safe to defer to it in the non-const version (but not vice-versa of course).

Are there any nasty surprises in the language that would ever make this a bad idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/856839/367273

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/123995/367273