# Pitfalls of implementing a reference getter with a const_cast of a const-ref getter

Tags: c++

I have a class, say, `vector<T>`. I want to implement two getter methods, returning `T&` and `const T&` respectively. I do not want to implement both of them. Instead I'd like to implement only const version and then reuse its code in a non-const method with `const_cast`.

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    T& operator[](size_t i) {
        return const_cast<T&>(
            static_cast<const Vector<T>*>(this)->operator[](i));
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t i) const {
        return data[i];
    }

private:
    T* data;
};
```

What are the possible pitfalls of this approach? Or, are there any methods to check that const_cast is legitimate in any exact case?

Finally, what are the good common ways to deal with such duplicated const/non-const code?

Comment: looks to me like more work and a worse maintenance headache than simply implementing the operator twice

Comment: *"Finally, what are the good common ways to deal with such duplicated const/non-const code?"* already has been asked and answered often enough on SO, I suggest you remove that.

Comment: Related to [elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters)

Comment: The main reasoning which helped is that the caller of non-const method has a non-const instance of my class, thus const_cast-ing is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One clean way is to delegate to a private template function which can deduce the constness of `this`:

```
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
      return impl_indirection(this, i);
    }

    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const {
      return impl_indirection(this, i);
    }

private:
  template<class MaybeConstVector>
    static decltype(auto) impl_indirection(MaybeConstVector* pv, std::size_t index)
  {
    return pv->data[index];
  }

  T* data;
};
```

Comment: I wish there were a builtin for that `const? T& operator[](...) const?;`.