# Optimal way to write two methods that return a value and reference of the same item in C++

Tags: c++, reference, refactoring, return-value

Suppose that I have a class that has two methods.  One of them should find an object in a container and return it by value, and the other one should return it by reference.  Naturally, I want the first method to be `const` (in the sense of `this` being `const`) and the second one not to be.

Is there a way to re-use the code between these two methods without introducing a third method that they both rely on?  Below I've given a toy example of the problem, where one should imagine that the `find` step is actually considerably more complicated.

In "possible implementation 1" below, there is an error due to the fact that I am calling (non-`const`) `get_ref` from within (`const`) `get_value`.  In "possible implementation 2," the reference is created from a temporary copy of the value, which of course is a major problem.

In the case that a `const` reference is desired, then of course there is no problem, but assume that I actually want an ordinary reference.

```
// Header:

#include <string>
#include <map>
using std::string;
using std::map;

class Test {
    public:
        map< string, string > stuff;
        string & get_ref( const string key );
        string get_value( const string key ) const;
};


// Possible implementation 1:

string Test::get_value( const string key ) const {
  return get_ref( key );
}

string & Test::get_ref( const string key ) {
  return stuff.find( key )->second;
}


// Possible implementation 2 (obviously wrong, but here for the sake of pointing that out):

string Test::get_value( const string key ) const {
  return stuff.find( key )->second;
}

string & Test::get_ref( const string key ) {
  return get_value( key );
}
```

Comment: Think a little about what `get_ref` is returning in the second implementation. If you try to actually *build* it what does the compiler tell you?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should also think about what happens if the key is not found and the `find` function returns the `end` iterator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you are alluding to the return of a temporary, the OP has already mentioned that as a reason not to use the second implementation

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I clearly stated that the second implementation is obviously bad.  Read my question.  I also said that this is a toy example meant to illustrate the problem.  An actual application would have error handling.

Comment: @TheDark Then I don't really see the meaning of including such clearly erroneous code, if the OP knows it will not work. To the OP: If you know that the second alternative won't work, then don't include it, it's just noise. Instead concentrate on the first alternative, and how to fix it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess you have a point, but I was mostly including it to point out that it isn't an option.  I will add to the comment above it

Comment: As for a possible solution to the first implementation, you *know* that `get_ref` doesn't in itself modify the object. It is, for all practical reasons, constant. So you could easily [cast away `const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) of `this` in the `get_value` function to be able to call `get_ref`. ***However*** this doesn't solve the problem that `get_ref` itself is flawed since you have no safe case if `key` is not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant solution to duplicate, const and non-const, getters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer the question, the only way to avoid using a third/private method is to cast the `const`-ness of `this` away.

Using the "possible implementation 1", alter as follows:

```
string Test::get_value( const string key ) const {
  return const_cast<Test*>(this)->get_ref( key );
}
```

Now, to look a bit broader at two other issues: firstly, you should alter `get_ref()` so it does something sensible if `stuff.find( key )` returns `end()` (the one-past-the-end iterator). Options include throwing an exception or returning an empty string.

Secondly, a simple efficiency improvement is to note that the method parameters pass strings by value, which can be easily and safely changed to pass `const string& key`.

Comment: I think I was typing the above at the same time as @someprogrammerdude :-S

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will go with a const_cast.  I've commented above that I understand that there should be error handling.  I just wanted to keep the example as brief as possible (one line in each function).  As for the relative speed of passing by value or reference, my understanding is that for small, built-in types, this depends more on the compiler than anything -- but this is something I know very little about.

Comment: As an aside to my own answer, I should also point out, when returning an empty string or similar - be careful. `return "";` is unsafe (returning reference to local/temp object). Better to declare a `static` member or static local variable and return that.