# Casting away const-ness of method

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior, const-cast

As a follow up to my previous question ([Writing to class member through const &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684754/writing-to-class-member-through-const)), is it also well defined and correct to cast away a class member method's const-ness like this?

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    : a(5)
    {
    }

    int run() const
    {
        std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
        int& x = (int&)a;
        x = 17;
        std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

private:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    A program;
    return program.run();
}
```

Output (tested with c++14 on cpp.sh with -O0, -Wall, -Wextra and -Wpedantic):

```
a: 5
a: 17
```

If not, what part of the standard would i refer to for an explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your code is valid, although not recommended, as long as the object instance you start with is non-`const` (which is the case in your code, `A program;` is non-const).

Removing `const`-ness from a `const` instance is UB (undefined behaviour). Removing `const`-ness from a casted-to-`const` initial non-`const` instance is well defined, see e.g. the documentation for [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast).

If you really need to modify a member variable from a `const` member function, consider marking the former as [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv). Otherwise your current technique will lead to UB whenever someone (by mistake) invokes your member function on a `const` instance.