# how to use non-const function in a const function?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-qualifier

I have the following `const` function that uses the `non-const` function `locate`. `locate` can not be `const` because it might return a reference to `*this` but it never changes anything in `this`. I would like to be able to call `locate` so that I am not duplicating code, so what is the right way to use this `non-const` functon in this case?

As you can see, I even make the result of `locate` a `const` but that doesn't guarantee that I don't change something from within `locate`. So is there a way to make functions temporarily constant or something?

```
bool SegmentNode::find(const Segment& ss) const {
    const SegmentNode& parent = locate(ss);
    for (Segment in : parent.overlap_beg()) {
        if (ss == in)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just duplicate locate with the const and non-const versions. If you don't want to repeat the code, you can use the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters

Comment: @LoPiTaL, thank you, I like this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to have two `locate` functions: one is `const` and the other isn't. You'll use a `const_cast` in the non-const version, and the resulting code is legal because the entry point for `SegmentNode` was non-const.

```
const SegmentNode& SegmentNode::locate(const Segment& s) const{
  // as you have it already
  return* this;
}

SegmentNode& SegmentNode::locate(const Segment& s){
  return const_cast<SegmentNode&>(static_cast<const SegmentNode*>(this)->locate(s));
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OB6XHcBwok0Xa6XF)

Obligatory edit: There should be two versions of `locate` anyway that account for `const`-ness. The solution I have above is just a way to avoid duplicating code, ugly as it is.

Comment: Thanks, this was first suggested by @LoPiTaL so I want to give him credit for the suggestion. but this is indeed what I have decided on doing.

Comment: @jdodle: I was working on my answer when L'Hospital posted their comment :-)

Comment: No problem! Good to know it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't (although you can force a `const_cast` but you should not).

To assure const-correctness `locate` should also be `const` OR `SegmentNode::find` should not be const. To help you, ask yourself why is `locate` not const if it never changes anything ?

Choose whatever is more appropriate for your case.