# Avoiding const/non-const duplication of method accepting a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, constants

`class Frame<P>` represents an image with pixels of type `P`. The algorithm that iterates through its pixels is non-trivial due to several flexibilities in the underlying data buffer format.

```
template <typename P, bool RM = true> // P is pixel type; RM = is_row_major
class Frame {

    // ...

    template<typename F>
    void iterate(F f) { // iterate in a way that is performant for this buffer
        if (stride == (RM ? size.w : size.h)) {
            auto n = size.area();
            for (index_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                f(view[k]);
            }
        }
        else {
            auto s = static_cast<index_t>(stride)*(RM ? size.h : size.w);
            for (index_t k0 = 0; k0 < s; k0 += stride) {
                auto m = k0 + (RM ? size.w : size.h);
                for (index_t k = k0; k < m; k++) {
                    f(view[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to call both `iterate(fc) const` and `iterate(f)` (with lambda signatures `fc(const P&)` and `f(P&)` respectively). I could duplicate the entire function body and attach `const` to the signature, but is there a better way?

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/856542/2412846) here help? (If not, then I obviously have not understood the question -- could you make it clearer,and possibly minimize your example?)

Comment: @davidhigh Not sure. I use that regularly on simple getters. Is it safe to use `const_cast` here too?

Comment: Use it on what? Frankly, I have not understood the question ... can you give an example in your question of what you want to do, with just two `operator+=` members, one const, one not-const?

Comment: @davidhigh For me `operator+=` is inherently non-const. What I want is an `iterateTogether() const` without duplicating the entire method.

Comment: Why can't you just have one `iterateTogether` function that is `const`? There is no problem calling a `const` member function from a non-const one.

Comment: @davidhigh I've simplified the question.

Comment: @ChrisDrew But the non-const version of `iterate()` should be able to pass argument to lambda by non-const reference, which the const version of `iterate()` will not allow.

Comment: @Museful OK, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const`ness of member functions cannot be deduced. However, using forwarding references allows deducing the `cost`ness of function arguments. Thus, you can just delegate to a function taking the object type as argument and forwarding all other arguments. This way the duplicated code becomes trivial. If the function needs access to `private` or `protected` members you’d just make it a (probably `private` ) `static` member:

```
template <typename T, bool PM = true>
class Frame {
    template <typename F1, typename F2>
    static void iterateTogether(F1&& f1, F2&& f2) {
        // actual implementation goes here
    }
public:
    template <typename F2>
    void iterateTogether(F2&& other){
        iterateTogether(*this, std::forward<F2>(other));
    }
    // ...
 };
```

The implementation used above also allows different `const`ness of the parameter. If you want to constrain the parameter to really just be a specialization of `Frame` you’d need to constrain the function which is, however, easily done.

My personal preference is having only trivial members anyway and delegate anything non-trivial to generic algorithms. My preference is that classes just maintain their invariants and interesting uses are implemented via algorithms.