# Why doesn't const_cast work on arguments to std::function?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, c++20, const-cast

I'm providing a const and non-const variation of a member function where I reuse the const version to implement the non-const version as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856839/115751) per Scott Meyers books.

The const version takes an argument of type:

```
const std::function< void (const Foo &) > &
```

vs the non-const takes an argument of type:

```
const std::function< void (      Foo &) > &
```

In the implementation, I have to use `reinterpret_cast` because `const_cast` is not working.

E.g.,:

```
const std::function< void (Foo &) > & Processor;
reinterpret_cast< const std::function< void (const Foo &) > & >( Processor );
```

vs

```
const std::function< void (Foo &) > & Processor;
const_cast< const std::function< void (const Foo &) > & >( Processor );
```

Wouldn't this be in the spirit of what `const_cast` is meant for?  Is this just an oversight in the language definition to perhaps be fixed in C++2x or would `const_cast` never be in the spirit of things here?

Here is more complete code:

```
void Collection::ProcessCollection(const std::function< void (const Foo &) > & Processor) const
{
    for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < m_LocalLimit ; )
    {
        if ( m_Data[ idx ] )
        {
            Processor( m_Data[idx] );
        }
    }

    const int overflowSize = OverflowSize();

    for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < overflowSize ; )
    {
        Processor( (*m_Overflow)[ idx ] );
    }
}

void Collection::ProcessCollection(const std::function< void (Foo &) > & Processor)
{
    const Collection * constThis = const_cast< const Collection * >( this );
    const std::function< void (const Foo &) > & constProcessor
        = reinterpret_cast< const std::function< void (const Foo &) > & >( Processor );

    constThis->ProcessCollection( constProcessor );
}
```

Comment: The `const_cast` applies to the type, not to a subtype as part of the signature of the parameters.

Comment: In the approach suggested by Scott, you `const_cast` the arguments so you can call the function.  Your code attempts to cast the function type (which will never be blessed by the standard).

Comment: @KamilCuk Question updated.

Comment: @M.M Fixed mismatched `< >` and full functions provided.

Comment: consider having `ProcessCollection` be a function template accepting a Callable  . At the cost of having code in the header, it's more concise, flexible and optimizable

Comment: @M.M That's what I'm trying due to the comments in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's not safe to use `const_cast` to cast away `const`ness that appears in template arguments. For example, consider this (admittedly, somewhat contrived) code:

```
template <typename T> struct Wrapper {
    int x;
};

template <> struct Wrapper<char *> {
    double y;
};
```

Here, a pointer to a `Wrapper<const char *>` points to a very different object than a `Wrapper<char *>`, so doing a `const_cast` to turn a `Wrapper<const char *> *` into a `Wrapper<char *> *` would result in a pointer to a `struct` containing an `int` now pointing at a `struct` containing a `double`, breaking some language rule whose name eludes me at the moment. :-)

Since in general it's not safe to `const_cast` this way, the language spec doesn't allow for `const_cast` to be used like this, which is why in your case, even though the operation makes intuitive sense, the language disallows your code with `const_cast`.

I am fairly certain that using a `reinterpret_cast` here leads to undefined behavior, since the language considers `std::function<T1>` and `std::function<T2>` to be different, incompatible types when `T1` and `T2` aren't the same. It may happen to work on your system by pure coincidence, but I don't believe you can safely assume this will work.

Comment: If not safe, how would I go about implementing a non-const variant in terms of a const one then in this situation?

Comment: You could have the non-const one pass in a lambda that does a const_cast to strip constness from its argument, then forwards it along to the function that was passed in as an argument, perhaps?

Comment: @WilliamKF easiest solution is not to use `std::function` but make your method template. It would be more efficient as well as `std::function` has overhead.

Comment: Using a lambda sounds like it would be expensive.  This code is in a critical loop, so it sounds like I should get rid of `std::function` even and templatize the function on the `Processor` function.

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret_cast` here is undefined behavior.  `const_cast` isn't appropriate, because the `const`ness of template parameters isn't something you can cast away.

The easy way to solve this is, well, don't.  Get rid of some references.  Swap who implements it.

```
void Collection::ProcessCollection(std::function< void (const Foo &) > Processor) const
{
  Collection * mutableThis = const_cast< Collection * >( this );

  mutableThis->ProcessCollection( Processor );
}

void Collection::ProcessCollection(std::function< void (Foo &) > Processor)
{
  for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < m_LocalLimit ; )
  {
    if ( m_Data[ idx ] )
    {
      Processor( m_Data[idx] );
    }
  }

  const int overflowSize = OverflowSize();

  for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < overflowSize ; )
  {
    Processor( (*m_Overflow)[ idx ] );
  }
}
```

`std::function` stores things that are call-compatible with it.

If you take a `Foo&`, you can call a function expecting a `Foo const&` with it.  So you can store a `std::function<void(Foo const&)>` within a `std::function<void(Foo&)>`.

Wrapping something in a `std::function` can involve allocating.  So you may want to find a high-quality `function_view<Sig>` to replace your use of `std::function`.

In another comment, you state that this code is in a critical loop.  Eliminating `std::function` entirely is a good move, or at least reducing the type erasure taps and passing batches of data to it somehow.

The inversion of const/unconst is still appropriate; we implement const in terms of mutable instead of mutable in terms of const because one is a covariant operation, the other is a contravariant operation.  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Comment: I'm using a lambda now instead of `std::function`, resulting in a significant speedup.  See related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56602770/115751).