# How to avoid code duplicate const and non-const collection processing with lambda

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constants, c++17

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters/856839#856839) does not work for this pattern in C++17:

```
template <typename Processor>
void Collection::ProcessCollection(Processor & processor) const
{
    for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < m_LocalLimit ; )
    {
        if ( m_Data[ idx ] )
        {
            processor( m_Data[idx] );
        }
    }

    const int overflowSize = OverflowSize();

    for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < overflowSize ; )
    {
        processor( (*m_Overflow)[ idx ] );
    }
}

// How to avoid this repetition for non-const version?
template <typename Processor>
void Collection::ProcessCollection(Processor & processor)
{
    for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < m_LocalLimit ; )
    {
        if ( m_Data[ idx ] )
        {
            processor( m_Data[idx] );
        }
    }

    const int overflowSize = OverflowSize();

    for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < overflowSize ; )
    {
        processor( (*m_Overflow)[ idx ] );
    }
}
```

Due to the argument passed to the lambda `Processor` being const and not matching its signature.

Comment: What exactly is the determining factor as to whether `ProcessCollection` is `const` or non-`const`? That is, who is making that decision?

Comment: @NicolBolas The `ProcessCollection` member functions are private and are called by other member functions, some of which are `const` and others which are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can factor out the function as a static template one and use it inside both. We can use the template to generate both of these functions:

```
struct Collection {
    // ...

    template<typename Processor>
    void ProcessCollection(Processor& processor) {
        ProcessCollectionImpl(*this, processor);
    }

    template<typename Processor>
    void ProcessCollection(Processor& processor) const {
        ProcessCollectionImpl(*this, processor);
    }

    template<typename T, typename Processor>
    static void ProcessCollectionImpl(T& self, Processor& processor) {
        for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < self.m_LocalLimit ; )
        {
            if ( self.m_Data[ idx ] )
            {
                processor( self.m_Data[idx] );
            }
        }

        const int overflowSize = self.OverflowSize();

        for( int idx = -1 ; ++idx < overflowSize ; )
        {
            processor( (*self.m_Overflow)[ idx ] );
        }
    }
};
```

The `T&` will deduce `Collection&` or `Collection const&` depending on the constness of `*this`