# Define const implementation of getter in child class shadows parrent class implementation. Why?

Tags: c++, inheritance, getter, vtable

I want to make interface with getter which calls virtual method from child. But now i have problems: implementation of const method in child shadows parent one. Why? I have tried to make parent Get non virtual (not working). Then I have tried switch const and mutable implementation -- same behaviour. But if I implement both it seems fine.

```
struct A {
    virtual const int& Get() const = 0 ;

    virtual int& Get() {
        return const_cast<int&>(const_cast<const A*>(this)->Get());
    }
   virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : A{
    int i{42};

    const int& Get() const override { return i; }
};

int main(){

    B b;
    b.Get() = 32; // error
    static_cast<A&>(b).Get() = 32;  //ok
    std::cout << b.i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why? Because it's the rules of C++. Shadowing is based on names not signatures.

Comment: A getter-type function is, by definition, is expected not to modify its object, and therefore should be `const`.

Comment: @john But I can implement virtual int& Get()  in **B** and it will act differently. So why am i need to explicitly implement it?

Comment: @AjBi I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean. But virtual functions have the same shadowing rules as any other kind of function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it is questionable(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters). We still have opportunity to do this in normal case. Why this is not working in mine?

Comment: Overloading occurs among functions defined in the same scope. `B::Get` and `A::Get` are not defined in the same scope, so there is no overloading, and the only version of `Get` for `b.Get()` is the one defined in `B`.

Comment: @PeteBecker In this case i should see the parent scope because inheritance is public. Or i miss something?

Comment: @AjBi -- the curly braces that mark the class `A` define a scope; the curly braces that mark the class `B` define a scope. `A::Get` is in the scope defined by `A`. `B::Get` is in the scope defined by `B`. `A::Get` and `B::Get` are not defined **in the same scope**, so they do not overload.